# What is the best way to fetch user location server side

Tags: zend-framework, geolocation, client-side

I know that the best way to fetch the user position (not only cords, but also country name and city name) is using client side script, right?

But I have seen that user can deny to say his position, so, how can I determinate it in the server side? What is the best way to do it? Is there any Zend Framework extension?

Comment: If the user deny to give this information to you, why do you want to get it?

Comment: Matthieu: Because he's bad! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with the IP but not 100% sure. You can look for web service like this one : http://www.ip2location.com/ or if you just want the country download the ip database.

Comment: there isn't official ones with zend, but you can build a web service with Zend_Service quite easily. You can get frameworkless I think you can get some informations from google. With these keyword `web service ip geolocation`. YOu have a library here : http://www.maxmind.com/app/php. Have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service

Comment: Have a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service and there maxmind.com/app/php.

Answer (score 0):

You can find visitors position according to IP addresses. This data is not as exact as gps position or cell data information although at least you can find out visitior's country.
PHP has core functionality to access ip:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

The are certain projects that can handle ip to place (country) conversion:
http://code.google.com/p/php-ip-2-country/